# Is it possible to make tree excel data from js tree object?

Tags: javascript, excel, treeview, xlsx

There is JSON like

```
let jsonData = [
   {
    parentColumnValue: val,
    ...someData,
    children: [
      parentColumnValue: val,
      ...someData,
      children: [
       ...
       in the end there is array of children objects with ...someData keys
      ]
    ]
   }
]
```

i need to transform in to excel file with data tree possibilities like in the picture below

[needed excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TyO5.png)

I already have possibility to get xlsx file from linear array of objects - using "xlsx": "^0.17.4" vue 2, but the question is about data-tree js file to data-tree excel file.

I tried to read documentation on xlsx library but did not found needed info.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/ on server side.

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer